# Ag-grid - How Can I Populate/Create a Drop Down From DB for Each row in the Grid

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I am working with AG-Grid and Vue Js and need to populate each grid row with their own dropdown values from a database. I was able to get a dropdown field working but all rows in the grid had the same set of dropdown items -(not correct either).

I need a way to either make Agrid know a column should have dropdown values or to allow me to set the values for each row in the grid.

```js
var tots = {"5d235": "test", "2": "Validée", "454": "A valider CEX", "4": "Demandée", "5":"Initialisée"}; 

        {headerName: 'Tot #', field: 'TotNumber',
                cellStyle: {overflow: 'visible', textAlign: 'center'},
                            editable:true,
                            cellEditor: "agSelectCellEditor",
                cellEditorParams: {
                        values: extractValues(tots) ,//hard coding will show the same tots for each row.
                        //values: extractValues(params.value), //this seems ideal but doesn't work because params was not passed in
                        //however if you passed in params on cellEditorParams:function(params), the dropdown is empty
                    },

            }
```

Each row should populate with its own list of dropdown items